# Filtering a data frame in R using a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and am running into difficulty with more advanced filtering. I have a data frame containing 1500 rows of people in households and need to filter out everyone who is part of a household where at least 1 person is older than 24. For example, in the sample set below I would only want to keep rows 3,4, and 5.

```
PersonalID     DOB         HouseholdID
1            1961-04-15      123
2            2017-01-12      123
3            2000-01-02      122
4            2001-03-05      122
5            1996-08-22      122
```

Initially I just filtered to get a new data frame with everyone in that age range and then filtered the original data frame again (and again and again and so on...) with each HouseholdID of someone under 25 to check if anyone else with that HouseholdID is over 24.

Whenever I'm doing the same thing over and over it seems like there's probably a way to use a function instead but I'm having a hard time coming up with one that works. This is my current attempt but I know there's plenty wrong with it:

```
UNDER25df <- filter(df, DOB >= "yyyy-mm-dd")

for (UNDER25df$HouseholdID in df) {
    if (all(df$DOB >= "yyyy-mm-dd")) {
       view(filter(df, HouseholdID == "$HouseholdID"))
     }
 }
```

The error I get is:

> unexpected '}' in "}"

but I'm pretty sure that I can nest an if statement in a for loop in R and that I've been careful about the positioning of the brackets so I don't know exactly what it's referring to.

What I'm not sure of is if I can iterate through a data frame in this way or if this even makes sense. I've read that vectoring might be better in general for advanced filtering but tried to read the documentation on it and couldn't really see how to make that jump to this problem. Does anyone have a suggestion or a direction I should be looking in?

Comment: Not sure why  you need a `for` loop here and the values in the comparison doesn't make sense `DOB >= "yyyy-mm-dd"` or `HouseholdID == "$HouseholdID"` or the looping `for (UNDER25df$HouseholdID in df)`. May be `df %>% group_by(HouseholdID) %>% filter(all(as.Date(DOB) >= as.Date("2010-01-01")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want keep the rows grouped by ID that all users are less than or equal to 24-year old. If so, then maybe you can try the code below

```
library(lubridate)
dfout <- subset(df, ave(floor(time_length(Sys.Date()-as.Date(DOB),"years"))<=24, HouseholdID, FUN = all))
```

- If you really want to use `for` loop to make it, then the below is an example

```
dfout <- data.frame()
for (id in unique(df$HouseholdID)) {
  subdf <- subset(df,HouseholdID == id)
  if (with(subdf, all(floor(time_length(Sys.Date()-as.Date(DOB),"years"))<=24))) {
    dfout <- rbind(dfout,subdf)
  }
}
```

Both approaches above can give you the result shown as

```
> dfout
  PersonalID        DOB HouseholdID
3          3 2000-01-02         122
4          4 2001-03-05         122
5          5 1996-08-22         122
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(PersonalID = 1:5, DOB = c("1961-04-15", "2017-01-12", 
"2000-01-02", "2001-03-05", "1996-08-22"), HouseholdID = c(123L, 
123L, 122L, 122L, 122L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a loop for this. Try

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(DOB = Sys.Date() - sample(3000:12000, 6), 
             personalID = 1:6,
             HouseholdID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3))
df$DOB

# grab householdID from all persons that are at least 24
oldies <- df[(lubridate::today() - lubridate::ymd(df$DOB)) > years(24),
             "HouseholdID", TRUE]

# base R way
oldies <- df[as.Date(df$DOB) > as.Date("1993-2-10"),
             "HouseholdID", TRUE]

# household members in a household with someone 24 or older
df %>% 
  filter(HouseholdID %in% oldies)


# household members in a household with noone 24 or older
df %>% 
  filter(!(HouseholdID %in% oldies))
```

Comment: Do I have to use lubridate? I have a specific time frame I'm working with so I know that for the purposes of my data under 25  means born on or after 10/2/1993

I created a new df filtered by those born before 10/2/93 and then tried using that with `df %>% filter(HouseholdID %in% oldies)` but this gave me a 0x106 tibble. Theoretically should this should give a dataframe of everyone in a household with someone 25 or over? Could I use this in some way to retain just those who are not in one of those households?

Comment: no, you dont have use lubridate but, in my opinion, it makes the code much more readable and easier to code. You can also use base R functions. Regarding your first question: yes this is the purpose. Second: yes, I also included this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to select household where all the people are above 24 or at least one person is above 24. In any case, you can use `subset` with `ave`

```
subset(df, ave(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")) - 
               as.integer(format(DOB, "%Y")) >= 24, HouseholdID, FUN = any))
```

This selects households where at least one person is above 24. If you want to select households where all people are above 24 use `all` instead of `any` in `FUN` argument.

Similarly, using `dplyr`, we can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(HouseholdID) %>%
   filter(any(as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")) - 
              as.integer(format(DOB, "%Y")) >= 24))
```